# PhoneGap - When deployed on device none of the styles or javascript files are loaded?

Tags: html, cordova

I am just writing a small part of a phonegap version of another app I am working on.

However I have hit a bizarre problem. When I run the html files locally via firefox all works fine and seems great. However when I deploy to the device the html file loads ok, however there are no styles, and none of the javascript seems to be loaded.

My directory structure is like: (original *A*ssets was a typo)

```
{project}/assets/www/
| - scripts/
| - styles/
| - index.html
```

My links from the index to css and js look like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
```

My apk file contains all these files (I have checked within Winrar), I thought maybe it was a case thing, but everything is lower case and referenced as so. I am deploying to Android 1.6 but have tried 2.1 and 2.2 as well, no luck there either.

Anyone had anything similar happen?

Comment: Fixed this issue. Ended up being a case issue, one of my js files had a capital on one of the folders. After using adb logcat from the platform-tools it told me the error and I could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Java source load Assets/index.html?  The loadUrl typically maps file:///android_asset/... to the assets directory. Note the **lowercase** assets.

There should be a file src/{packageName}/{activityName}.java that looks like :

```
package {packageName}; 
import com.phonegap.*;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class activity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }`

}
```

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I thought by mentioning that it displays the page without styles implied that it loaded the index.html, just didnt load anything that it referenced. Will update initial post to make this point clearer.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem if I put index.html directly in the assets directory. If it is in a subdirectory of assets - like 'www' or anything else - the css and scripts load fine.

Comment: sorry, again I have not been entirely accurate with my initial post as it was done away from my phonegap computer. My index.html files are within the "www" folder within assets... again will update my main post. Still cannot get it working :(